# How to jitter lines in ggplot2

Tags: r, graph, plot, ggplot2, overlap

Say I have the following data and plot:

```
require(reshape2)
require(ggplot2)
data <- data.frame(id=seq(1,9,1), var1=c(10,3,5,7,8,9,4,6,5), var2=c(9,3,5,7,8,9,4,6,5))
data_graph <- melt(data, id="id")
ggplot(data=data_graph, aes(y=value, x=id, group=variable, col=variable)) +
geom_line(size=2) + geom_point() + 
geom_text(aes(label=value), size=5, hjust=-.6, vjust=1.5)
```

For almost the entirety of both lines, there is overlap. Is there any way to somehow jitter the lines so that they are close to each other, but don't overlap. Or to do something to know that there are two lines?

Comment: does adding `linetype=variable` help (probably not much)

Comment: see a related question and solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39533456/r-how-to-jitter-both-geom-line-and-geom-point-in-ggplot2-linegraph

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a function to do just this called `jitter`. If you just want to add jitter to the lines in the plot, the following code will do it:

```
ggplot(data=data_graph, aes(y=value, x=id, group=variable, col=variable)) +
  geom_line(size=2, 
            aes(y = jitter(value, 5), x = jitter(id, 2), group=variable, col=variable)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_text(aes(label=value), size=5, hjust=-.6, vjust=1.5)
```

The second value in the `jitter` function specifies how much jitter to add