# How to jitter both geom_line and geom_point by the same magnitude?

Tags: r, ggplot2, jitter

I have a `ggplot2` linegraph with two lines featuring significant overlap. I'm trying to use `position_jitterdodge()` so that they are more visible, but I can't get the lines and points to both jitter in the same way. I'm trying to jitter the points and line horizontally only (as I don't want to suggest any change on the y-axis). Here is an MWE:

```
## Create data frames
dimension <- factor(c("A", "B", "C", "D"))
df <- data.frame("dimension" = rep(dimension, 2),
                 "value" = c(20, 21, 34, 32,
                             20, 21, 36, 29),
                 "Time" = c(rep("First", 4), rep("Second", 4)))
## Plot it
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = dimension, y = value,
                      shape = Time, linetype = Time, group = Time)) +
    geom_line(position = position_jitterdodge(dodge.width = 0.45)) +
    geom_point(position = position_jitterdodge(dodge.width = 0.45)) +
    xlab("Dimension") + ylab("Value")
```

Which produces the ugly:

[image: Line/point mismatch]

I've obviously got something fundamentally wrong here: What should I do to make the `geom_point` jitter follow the `geom_line` jitter?

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44656299/lines-connecting-jittered-points-dodging-by-multiple-groups/44657850#44657850

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Another option for horizontal only would be to specify `position_dodge` and pass this to the `position` argument for each geom.

```
pd <- position_dodge(0.4)

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = dimension, y = value,
                      shape = Time, linetype = Time, group = Time)) +
  geom_line(position = pd) +
  geom_point(position = pd) +
  xlab("Dimension") + ylab("Value")
```

[image]

Comment: I'd definitely mark John's solution as the most appropriate answer @drgibbon.

Comment: Thanks - though I'm curious as to why? They both seem to accomplish the same thing. One of the features of ggplot that amazes me is how many ways there are to seemingly accomplish the same thing. This just happened to be the way I knew...

Comment: @hrbrmstr Done :) Pretty basic question I guess, but the help is much appreciated.

Comment: Btw, for my actual dataset, it seems like a combination of the two answers is producing quite nice results.

Comment: In reply to John's "why": (a) you more appropriately "keep it in ggplot2" and don't mess with the original data frame (b) you use a function that under the  covers actually calls the much more robust [`collide()`](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/c2d91dcebe81b53a7d0dafccc01be98737d5c026/R/position-collide.r) function to achieve the jitter; (c) you cleverly made a "dodge" object outside of the plot to ensure the points would receive the same randomness. Top notch & a far more proper idiomatic solution IMO.

Comment: Note this example only works 'by chance'. You need to sort your factor levels in order to make this 'safe'. See this GitHub issue: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3535

Answer (score 15):

One solution is to manually jitter the points:

```
df$value_j <- jitter(df$value)

ggplot(df, aes(dimension, value_j, shape=Time, linetype=Time, group=Time)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x="Dimension", y="Value")
```

[image]

The horizontal solution for your discrete X axis isn't as clean (it's clean [under the covers](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/R/position-jitter.r) when ggplot2 does it since it handles the axis and point transformations for you quite nicely) but it's doable:

```
df$dim_j <- jitter(as.numeric(factor(df$dimension)))

ggplot(df, aes(dim_j, value, shape=Time, linetype=Time, group=Time)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(labels=dimension) +
  labs(x="Dimension", y="Value")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that was fast. I just updated my question in that I'm trying to get horizontal jitter only, is that possible this way?

Comment: @drgibbon you would add the jitter to the x value (dimension) not the y value (value_j).  Or using geom_jitter you can set `height=0` to do horizontal jitter only

Comment: Added the horizontal solution but it's a bit hokey since your X axis is no longer really discrete (as the answer states, ggplot2 does this cleanly under the covers for you).

Comment: That's great thanks. I have to admit that the vertical jitter looks a lot better. I'll play around with it and see what works.

Answer (score 11):

On July 2017, developpers of `ggplot2` have added a `seed` argument on `position_jitter` function (https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/pull/1996).

So, now (here: `ggplot2 3.2.1`) you can pass the argument `seed` to `position_jitter` in order to have the same `jitter` effect in `geom_point` and `geom_line` (see the official documentation: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/position_jitter.html)

Note that this `seed` argument does not exist (yet) in `geom_jitter`.

```r
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = dimension, y = value,
                      shape = Time, linetype = Time, group = Time)) +
  geom_line(position = position_jitter(width = 0.25, seed = 123)) +
  geom_point(position = position_jitter(width = 0.25, seed = 123)) +
  xlab("Dimension") + ylab("Value")
```

[image]

Comment: As above, this example only works 'by chance'. You need to sort your factor levels in order to make this 'safe'. See this GitHub issue: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3535

Comment: @Tjebo, Interesting discussion. Thanks for sharing it. Here, as OP's example is already sorted, it works but you are right in some conditions with more complex dataset, it will require an additional step to sorted the dataframe first.

Comment: Thanks dc37 and @Tjebo, it's very cool that these questions accrue new knowledge/techniques over time.

Comment: @dc37 : could you please edit your answer to add the sorting step necessary for it to work in all cases ? (as explained in the github issued) I think this is the most elegant solution to this problem.